# Do coca leaves help relieve symptoms of altitude sickness?

Tags: alternative-medicine, medications

Coca leaves are widely used to relieve symptoms of altitude sickness in some South American countries, either chewed or brewed into a tea. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca_tea) says that no study has studied their effectiveness for this purpose, citing this as a source: https://www.wemjournal.org/article/S1080-6032(14)00257-9/fulltext

That was from 2014 and I could not find anything more recent on altitude sickness specifically, but https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3001837/ says

> These experimental findings suggest that chewing coca leaves is beneficial during exercise and that the effects are felt over a prolonged period of sustained physical activity

suggesting that there *could* be some positive effect. Given how widely used coca leaves seem to be, I would be really surprised that nobody has studied this at all.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Nice question.

Comment: I’ll be surprised if it has no effect, because I heard it was a hell of a drug. :p

Comment: The lack of research shouldn't be too surprising. [Coca is largely prohibited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca#International_prohibition_of_coca_leaf) and that usually includes a de facto prohibition on scientific investigation.

Comment: well if you're talking about fatigue or headache, there's lot of evidence to show stimulants would counter that. If you're talking about sleeplessness, then notsomuch. In short, it's indicated by _some_  symptoms, but not others. I guess that would make it "true", since there are some symptoms relived by coca.

Comment: I don't have hard evidence, only anecdotal from friends traveling here its effects are likely of a strong coffee while being even less addictive.